# Filtered git repo to remove large files from history. Successful on working copy but not shown in remote repo after push

Tags: git

I have removed some large files committed in error to a git repo using the suggestion by Gary Gauh in [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

```
 git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *jpg' HEAD
```

This has decreased the size of the repo's `./git/objects` directory from 50M to 35M.

When I `git commit` and `git push` this directory I am told that there is nothing to do. My assumption is that the commit has been pushed.

However when I check the size of the `.git/objects` directory on the server's repo directory, I see the `objects` directory is still 50M.

So -- what did I miss?

Comment: «Nothing to do» means that what you have attempted to push exactly matches the state held in the remote repo, and so there was literally nothing to do — as you did not have any new history for the remote repo to consume. Please make sure you did not run the `git filter-branch` command while being in a "detached HEAD" state—as otherwise the command would have just updated the `HEAD` ref, not touching any local branch.

Comment: Another fact worth considering is that the stock Git implementation uses _lazy_ garbage collection, and the fact you did overwrite some sizeable chunk of history with a slimmer version of the same chunk generally means nothing for the remote repo: by default, all the "replaced" commits will still be there, dangling, and would only be deleted when the next `git gc` or `git repack` prunes them. Garbage collection happens automatically when certain (configurable) thresholds are met—such as the number of dangling objects.

Comment: Hence if you really-really need to reclaim space then after _successful_ push (which should have required the `--force` parameter for the `git push` command as you were about to _replace_ some history), you should log to the server and run `git gc --force --aggressive` with the credentials of the account which owns the repo.

Comment: Another case to consider (for completeness): Git repos support the so-called "reflog": each "drastic branch head movement" is recorded in a special expirable log. The reflog is by default enabled in "normal" repositories and disabled in "bare" repositories (those are most of the time used to host public shared repos). If you were having the reflog enabled in the destination repo, replacing of some history in there would make the tip commit of the replaced chain of commits to be put in the reflog, which would make the reflog reference that history until that record expires.

Comment: …in such situation, running `git gc --force --aggressive` would do nothing to the size of the repo—you'd need to force-expire the reflog first. I'm not sure that's your case but I'm posting this here for the next reader. ;-)

Comment: @kostix. These comments should be in an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Here we go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Nothing to do» means that what you have attempted to push exactly matches the state held in the remote repo, and so there was literally nothing to do — as you did not have any new history for the remote repo to consume.
Please make sure you did not run the `git filter-branch` command while being in a "detached HEAD" state—as otherwise the command would have just updated the `HEAD` ref, not touching any local branch.

Another fact worth considering is that the stock Git implementation uses lazy garbage collection, and the fact you did overwrite some sizeable chunk of history with a slimmer version of the same chunk generally means nothing for the remote repo: by default, all the "replaced" commits will still be there, dangling, and would only be deleted when the next [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) prunes them. Garbage collection happens automatically when certain ([configurable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gcauto)) thresholds are met—such as the number of dangling objects.

Hence if you really-really need to reclaim space then after successful push— which should have required the `--force` parameter for the `git push` command as you were about to replace some history,—you should log to the server and run `git gc --force --aggressive` with the credentials of the account which owns the repo.

Another case to consider (for completeness): Git repos support the so-called ["reflog"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): each "drastic branch head movement" is recorded in a special expirable log. The reflog is by default enabled in "normal" repositories and disabled in "bare" repositories (those are most of the time used to host public shared repos), but [may be enabled there](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corelogAllRefUpdates). If you were having the reflog enabled in the destination repo, replacing of some history in there would make the tip commit of the replaced chain of commits to be put in the reflog, which would make the reflog reference that history until that record expires.
In such situation, running git `gc --force --aggressive` would do nothing to the size of the repo—you'd need to force-expire the reflog first; otherwise you'd need to wait until these references [expire automatically](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gcreflogExpire).